Why isnt my Dropdown menu being rendered when a new user logs but once the page is refreshed it does?
My dropdown menu isnt being rendered when a new user logs because the accountId is unidentified. But I pass down accountId from two parent compnents.I am wondering if that is the cause?
I originally pass it down from App.js through useContext into home and then I grab accountid from there and pass it further down.
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import CreateUsers from './Pages/CreateUsers';
import Login from './Pages/Login';
import Leftbar from './Leftbar';
 import LandingPage from './Pages/LandingPage';
 import Tolpbar from './Tolpbar';
import CreateTournaments from './Pages/CreateTournaments';
import MyTournaments from './Pages/MyTournaments';
import AccountUser from './Pages/AccountUser';
import CompetitorView from './Pages/CompetitorView';
import {AuthContext} from './helpers/AuthContext';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Routes,Navigate} from 
'react-router-dom';

const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

function App() {
const [authState, setAuthState] = useState({username:"", id:0, 
status:false,accoint_id:0});




useEffect(() => {
console.log("firing api");
if (!accessToken) {
  // Handle the case where there is no access token (e.g., 
 redirect to login page)
   setAuthState({...authState, status:false});
  } else{
  axios.get("http://localhost:3001/users/auth", {
    headers: {
  accessToken: accessToken,
},
})
 .then((response) => {
  console.log("got a response", response);
  if (response.data.error) {
    setAuthState({...authState, status:false});
  } else {
    console.log(response.data.username);
    setAuthState({username:response.data.username, id:response.data.id, status:true,accoint_id:response.data.account_id});
  }
});
}
},[]); 


return (
<div className="container-fluid">
<Router>
<AuthContext.Provider value={{authState, setAuthState}}>
<div className='row flex-nowrap'>
<Tolpbar/>
</div>
<div className='row flex-nowrap'>
{authState.status ?(
  <div class="col-auto col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-dark">    
        <Leftbar />
  </div>
) : null}
  <div className='col'>
    <Routes>
    <Route path='/Login' exact element ={<Login/>} />
      <Route path='/CreateUsers' exact element ={<CreateUsers/>} />
      <Route path='/' element={!accessToken ? <Navigate to="/LandingPage" /> : <Navigate to="/Home" />} />
      <Route path='/AccountUser' exact element ={<AccountUser/>} />
      <Route path='/CompetitorView' exact element = {<CompetitorView/>} />
      <Route path='/LandingPage' exact element ={<LandingPage/>} />
      <Route path='/CreateTournaments' exact element ={<CreateTournaments/>} />
      <Route path='/MyTournaments' exact element= {<MyTournaments />} />
      <Route path='/Home' exact element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  </div>

</div>

</AuthContext.Provider> 
</Router>
</div>
  );
}
export default App;

import axios from 'axios';
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';
import { useState, } from 'react';
import CustomModal from './CustomModal';

const ItemList = ({ items, accountId }) => {
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [openStates, setOpenStates] = useState(Array(items.length).fill(false));
  const handleShowModal = () => setShowModal(true);
  const handleCloseModal = () => setShowModal(false);

  const toggleDropdown = (index) => {
    const newOpenStates = [...openStates];
    newOpenStates[index] = !newOpenStates[index];
    setOpenStates(newOpenStates);
  };

  const onDelete = (tournamentName) => {
    if (!accessToken) {
      console.error('Access token not found. Delete request cannot be made.');
      return;
    }

    axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/tournaments`, {
      headers: {
        accessToken: accessToken,
      },
      data: {
        tournament_name: tournamentName,
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log('Tournament deleted successfully.');
        window.location.reload();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error deleting tournament:', error);
      });
  };


  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Start Date</th>
          <th>End Date</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {items.map((item, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{item.tournament_name}</td>
            <td>{item.start_date}</td>
            <td>{item.end_date}</td>
            <td>
              {accountId === item.account_id ? (
                <Dropdown show={openStates[index]} onClick={() => toggleDropdown(index)}>
                  <Dropdown.Toggle variant="primary" id={`dropdown-basic-${index}`}>
                    Edit
                  </Dropdown.Toggle>
                  <Dropdown.Menu>
                    <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => onDelete(item.tournament_name)}>Delete</Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item onClick={handleShowModal}> Edit Tournament</Dropdown.Item>
                    <CustomModal showModal={showModal} handleClose={handleCloseModal} accountId={accountId} tournament_id={item.tournament_id} />
                  </Dropdown.Menu>
                </Dropdown>
              ) : (
                <h6> Not your Tournament</h6>
              )}
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default ItemList;


Also a helper for createcontext:
import { createContext} from 'react';

export const AuthContext = createContext("");

I tried console.logging the accountId and saw it was undefined but I passed it down as a prop from two levels but I dont quite understand why thats the issue here or if it is the issue here.

What is the value of accountId if you log it in the parent components? Is there a spot you can trace it to where it has a value?

you don't show us where accountId  is being created/set, so it is hard to know. My guess is that it is not a piece of state, and therefore changing it does not trigger a child re-render.

I updated the code for where its being created thank you for the tip @dqhendricks

@144 It dosent have  a value starting from app.js at first login

I can't be sure on the interaction between useContext and passing the value on to a child as a prop. typically you would have every component that needs the value, useContext to get the value, and when the value changes it would force a re-render of each of those components. but my first advice would be to check and make sure both values are the same type (you aren't comparing a number value to a string value, as that would always produce false when using ===). the next thing I would try is having the component using the value, subscribe to the value directly with useContext
